# After Copy-Paste, Dependent DropDown List clears everything next to it

Tags: excel, dropdown, vba

I am new to this and I'm self-taught, so please let me know if there is something I'm doing wrong.

I have an inventory where two of the columns contain dropdown lists; 1 parent and 1 dependent (the dependent is 1 cell to the right of the parent). The code below is meant to clear the dependent list when the parent list is altered, and that part works.

However, if I copy-paste the cells that contain the lists (I have a lot of items in the inventory, so I was doing this to save time), then every cell to the right of the leftmost cell is cleared, including one additional cell to the right.

e.g. A1 contains the parent list, B1 contains the dependent list and C1 contains other information. I copy paste the three cells into Row 2. A2 is left intact, but B2 and C2 are blank (the copied information is not there), and D2 is cleared of any information.

Why is this happening?

Code:

```
 Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    On Error Resume Next
    If Target.Column = 3 Then 'The Parent list is in Column C
      If Target.Validation.Type = 3 Then
       Application.EnableEvents = False
       Target.Offset(0, 1).ClearContents 'The Dependent list is in Column D
      End If
    End If

exitHandler:
  Application.EnableEvents = True
  Exit Sub

End Sub
```

Comment: I suspect that because you are pasting a range, that entire range A2:C2 hits this function as the `Target` and then the entire range makes it through your `IF` statements. Then the range is offset to `B2:D2` and it's cleared. Perhaps add a check like `If Target.Column = 3 AND Target.Cells.Count = 1` to insure this only fires when `target` range is a single cell.

Comment: Ah that makes sense!

Comment: Thank you JNevill, that fixed it!